# ImageResizer license for website with one domain per language

Tags: imageresizer

When purchasing **Performance** licenses, the ImageResizer website states that it comes with "**1 wildcard domain**".

I was under the impression that Performance licenses apply to multiple domains, if those domains are simply aliases for the same website?

In this case, the different domains are used to separate different language versions of a website:

**tempuri.com** -> English website

**tempuri.se** -> Swedish website

This is instead of using a common domain and URL prefixes, something like:

**tempuri.com/en** -> English

**tempuri.com/se** -> Swedish

In the first case, would we need 1 license per domain?

Also, if the domains aren't exactly the same (depending on domain availability) like...

**tempuri.com ->** English

**tempuri-sweden.se** -> Swedish

**tempuri-denmark.dk** -> Danish

...would we then require **3 licenses** to support the three languages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance licenses include exactly 1 domain; they are tied to the HTTP HOST header that ImageResizer receives. While subdomains are included, unrelated domains are not. All documentation is very clear on this point - it is a domain license, not a site or website or server license. http://imageresizing.net/plugins/editions/performance

ImageResizer Elite licenses are DRM-free and can be used on an unlimited number of domains.